# Получение бинарных данных из объекта QVariant. При преобразовании целого числа в QByteArray появляются лишние байты

Tags: c++, qt, форматирование

Делаю преобразование целочисленного `QVariant` в объект `QByteArray`, так, чтобы там было байтовое представление этого числа.

Делаю:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QDataStream>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    qDebug() << "size of int:" << sizeof(int);
    QVariant var((int)0xF123);
    QByteArray data(sizeof(int),(char)0);
    qDebug() << "data before all:" << data.toHex();

    QDataStream ds(&data,QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    ds << var;

    qDebug() << "size of data:" << data.size();
    qDebug() << "var to binary byte array:" << data./*right(4).*/toHex();

    return 0;
}
```

На выходе получаю:

```
size of int: 4
data before all: "00000000"
size of data: 9
var to binary byte array: "00000002000000f123"
```

Откуда взялось девять байт вместо четырех?

Можно, конечно, явно преобразовать тип `var` перед отправкой в `QDataStream`, например так:

```
ds << var.toInt();
```

Но в реальной программе мне незивестен заранее тип в `QVariant`, и не хотелось бы делать `switch` с перечистелием всех возможных числовых `typeId` переменной `var`, а сделать это элегантно.

По сути задача сводится к получению сырых данных из объекта `QVariant` и их размеров (по сути размер можно получить по `typeId`, но потом надо проверять длинным switch'ем, значение `QVariant::type()`, к тому же учитывать, что `QMetaType::Int` в разных средах может иметь разный размер и придется еще сравнивать с `sizeof(int)`

**P.S.** Нашел интереснейшую страницу по теме:
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-35510?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&showAll=true

Comment: QByteArray тут выглядит, конечно, как из пушки по воробьям. Получить указатель на переменную с числом попробуйте. И по указателю читайте нужно число байт.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов по сути задача сводится к получению сырых данных из объекта `QVariant` их размеров (по сути размер можно получить по typeId, но потом надо проверять длинным switch'ем, значение `QVariant::type()`, к тому же учитывать, что `QMetaType::Int` в разных средах может иметь разный размер и придется еще сравнивать с `sizeof(int)`

Comment: А QVariant::toByteArray() не даст ли искомых данных?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов
Согласно документации `QVariant::toByteArray()`:


"Returns the variant as a QByteArray if the variant has userType() QMetaType::QByteArray or QMetaType::QString (converted using QString::fromUtf8()); otherwise returns an empty byte array."

Однако реально `QVariant var(333);` дало при `var.toByteArray();` 'текстовое представление числа `"333"`

Comment: Посмотрите [этот вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537186/serializing-qvariant-through-qdatastream) и ответы к нему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QDataStream` имеет собственный формат данных, близкий к аппаратному представлению числа, но отличающийся от него. Если вы пишите в `QByteArray` через `QDataStream`, то и читать нужно через него же (через другой экземпляр `QDataStream`). И непонятно, зачем вы засунули 0 в начало массива - он тут явно не к месту, не стоит смешивать свои данные с данными `QDataStream`.

Должно быть примерно так:

```
QByteArray data;

{
   QDataStream out(&data, QIODevice::WriteOnly);

   int value = 0xF123;
   out << value;
}
// Предполагаем, что мы записали данные в файл, а потом считали их:
QByteArray inputData = data;
{
   QDataStream in(&data, QIODevice::ReadOnly);

   int value;
   in >> value; // тут ещё хорошо бы проверять на ошибки
   qDebug() << QString::number(value, 16);
}
```

Если хотите работать с "сырыми" данными - не используйте `QDataStream`

```
QByteArray data;
{
   int value = 0xF123;
   data.append(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value), sizeof(value));
}
{
   int value = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(data.data());
   qDebug() << QString::number(value, 16);

   // или
   qDebug() << data.toHex();
}
```

Comment: Основной вопрос, как получить данные из объекта `QVariant` и элегантно распознать их размер не проверяя каждый тип; из int'а их получить не составляет труда.

Comment: @asianirish , Хорошего способа получить сырые данные из   QVariant кроме как через сериаллизацию через `QDatastream` я не знаю, но есть устаревший метод `data` и `constData`, который доступен по крайней мере в Qt 5.5 . На самом деле большой пользы вы от него не получите, т.к. для работы с сырыми данными вам всё-рано нужно знать, какого они типа и использовать switch-case по типам. Я его использую только из-за того, что мне нужно ссылка на хранимое значение на некоторое время, но метод `value` и аналоги возвращают копию. Возможно, вам стоит посмотреть в сторону boost/std::variant и any.

Answer (score 0):

Вдохновляясь комментариями @Ariox (пользуясь случаем выражаю благодарность, спасибо) и [следующей](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-35510?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&showAll=true) перепиской 
нашел такое кошерное/некошерное (нужное подчеркнуть) решение:

Переделанный пример выглядит так:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QVariant var((int)0xF123);

    qDebug() << "source number:" << QString::number(var.toInt(), 16);

    QMetaType mt(var.type());

    char *buf;
    buf = (char*)var.constData();

    QByteArray ba; //тоже сойдет: ((char*)buf, QMetaType::sizeOf(var.type()));
    ba.setRawData(buf, QMetaType::sizeOf(var.type()));

    qDebug() << ba.toHex();

    QVariant target(var.type(), ba.data());
    qDebug() << "target number:" << QString::number(target.toInt(), 16);

    return 0;
}
```

То есть воспользовался недокументированной, но открытой функцией `QVariant::constData`.

"Кошерное" (но неправильное) использование `QByteArray` не понадобилось. Размер типа в `QVariant`, как оказалось, легко узнается через `QMetaType::sizeOf`

IMHO `QVariant::constData` нужно оставить и документировать, несмотря на опасения за ее "небезопасность", так как сам язык C++, по сути, небезопасный, позволяет выстрелить в ногу и возлагает много ответственности на самого программиста, зачем же лишать программиста всех возможностей `QVariant`, если по другому определенные задачи не решаются?

P.S. Возможно в будущем они откроют и документируют `QVariant::convert(const int t, void ptr) const` вместо `QVariant::constData`